# Why are the bottom two else if statements not executing?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

The last two elif statements won't work; it simply redirects me to either of the previous two.  And for the else statement, it won't print the number of points. Why is this code not working? Thanks!

```
def match_duel():

    print "do you want to swing right or left"
    print "and for how many points?"

    choice = raw_input("> ")
    points = 0
    damage = 0

    if "right" in choice:
        print "you take a swing right. 20 points."
        points = points + 20
        print "You have %d points" % points
        match_duel()
    elif "left" in choice:
        print "you take a swing left. 50 points."
        points = points + 50
        print "You have %d points" % points
        match_duel()
    elif "hard right" in choice:
        print "you take a hard swing right for 100 points."
        print "cthulhu strikes back with 100 points."
        print "you take half the damage."
        points = points + 100
        damage = damage - 50
        print "You have %d points" % points
        print "You have %d damage" % damage
        match_duel()
    elif "hard left" in choice:
        print "you take a hard swing left for 200 points."
        print "cthulhu strikes back with 50 points, taken by surprise."
        print "you take half the damage"
        points = points + 200
        damage = damage - 25
        print "You have %d points" % points
        print "You have %d damage" % damage
        match_duel()
    else:
        print "take an extended hit."
        points = points + 300
        print "You have %d points" % points
```

Comment: Think about it: if `"hard left" in choice` than what is the value of `"left" in choice`? Hence which condition should go first?

Comment: So test for `"hard left"` *before* testing for a simple `"left"`.

Comment: Right.  As your code stands, you can never reach either of the last two clauses.

Comment: You could use @RadLexus solution or simply `command == choice` just I'd make `choice = raw_input("> ").strip().lower()`

Answer (score 0):

Only one `elif` statement here can be executed. The first one that satisfies the condition will be the one that gets executed - the rest are ignored.

"left" will **always** be in "hard left", no matter what. Same with "hard right". As such, the bottom 2 `elif` statements will never be executed.